# AWS SES Template changes links when sending

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm testing out email-templates on AWS SES and when I send an email using send-templated-email on my CLI, all the emails I receive contain my domain name + /CL0/ + the original URL + other stuff.

For example, if on my email template I have:

```
<a href="https://example.com/faq.html">link</a>
```

The email that is sent contains the following instead:

```
<a href="https://example.com/CL0/https:%2F%example.com%2Ffaq.html/1/...">link</a>
```

There is more stuff after the /1/ but I don't understand that part.
The problem is all the URLs return 404 because they've changed.

Is this an error or just how it works?

Answer (score 4):

You can disable click tracking for individual links by adding an attribute, ses:no-track.

```
<a ses:no-track href="https://example.com/faq.html">link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable it for all links in your emails, go to your AWS console > Amazon SES > (Choose the right region) > Configuration Sets (from the left panel) > for each of the sets, go to "Event Types" and uncheck "click" at the bottom and save.